# Gradient of a curve $y=\ln \sqrt{x+y}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, logarithms

Find the gradient of the curve $y=\ln \sqrt{x+y}$ at the point when its y-coordinate is 1.

My attempt,

I differentiated and I got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2x+2y-1}$.

But I've problem in finding the $x$.

$y=\ln \sqrt{x+y}$

$1=\ln \sqrt{x+1}$

How to proceed then?

Comment: Maybe it is useful that $\ln \sqrt{x+y} = 0.5 \ln (x+y)$

Comment: If $y=1$ then $x = e^2 -1$  gradient at $(e^2 -1, 1) = \frac{1}{2e^2-1}$

Answer (score 3):

$$x+y=e^{2y}$$
Then
$$2e^{2y}\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{dy}{dx}$$
From which
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2e^{2y}-1}$$

Comment: Sorry error in editing assumed mine, error due to similarity ..

Answer (score 0):

$$1=\ln \sqrt{x+1}\implies e^1=\sqrt{x+1}\implies e^2=x+1\implies x=e^2-1 $$

Comment: I found the answer which is $\frac{dy}{dx}=0.07258$ But the given answer is $0.225$. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Why  bother at all about x when

$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2 e^{ 2 y}-1 }? $$

Given answer is wrong, yours correct.

Answer (score 0):

$y=\ln \sqrt{x+y}$

$\implies \sqrt{x+y}=e^y$

$\implies x+y=(e^y)^2$

$\implies x+y=e^{2y}$

$\implies 1+\frac{dy}{dx}=2e^{2y}\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2e^{2y}-1}$